# I have to use control+left click to move an object using the 3d arrows

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, 3d-manipulator

Part of why this is an issue is that when I hold down the control button and use the movement arrows it turns on snapping for that object. I also have to use control+left click to connect things in the node editor. I've tried resetting the settings, deleting the folder blender is in then reinstalling it, restarting my computer and updating my graphics card and any outstanding drivers, but nothing has fixed it yet.

Answer (score 1):

May be the **snap to** function is enabled. To disable press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also try deleting the folder located at C:/Users/[your username]/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/
This will erase all configurations saved by blender

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. Thanks for the input though! I didn't know about the AppData blender storage!